# How do sections of RAM get marked as read-only in Embedded Systems

Tags: embedded, executable, ram, loader, readonly

When we build an executable, and it gets loaded into RAM, my understanding is that the `.text` and `.ro` setions should be loaded into read-only memory locations. With an operating system and a virtual memory controller I can understand how the different sections could get loaded to the right memory locations.

However, considering a bare-metal system without an operating system and an ARM chip for example. How is the read-only attribute of those sections achieved. They could be stored in ROM or Flash? But then doesn't everything get loaded into RAM anyways? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the CPU variant. What CPU / MMU do you have?

Comment: If it's a lower end ARM like Cortex M it will not load the program into RAM but execute directly from flash. That's the far most common approach in microcontrollers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Objects marked as `const` are checked by the compiler, that no statement writes into them. Executable code cannot be a target of such statements. Both are commonly linked into the sections `.text` and `.rodata`, respectively, or similar, as you write.

Embedded systems with ROM (masked ROM, EPROM, EEPROM, Flash, are all regarded the same here) will commonly have these sections in the ROM. Usually there is no need to copy it into precious RAM. Just look at the sizes of ROM and RAM, and you know, why. Such systems execute the machine code directly from the ROM, and read constant data from the ROM.

Embedded systems with RAM faster than ROM may copy `.text` and/or `.rodata` into RAM for better performance. If such a system has a memory management unit with protection capability, the loader will set these ranges to "read-only" after copying. Now the hardware stops your program from writing into this memory. BTW, I would not call this loader an "operating system", it is more a "bootloader".

If you have a system with RAM and no support to write-protect it, and it uses RAM for machine code and constant data, you need to rest on the correctness of your compiler, and of your program.

Answer (score 1):

To protect RAM from writes you need a CPU with an MMU. It is not difficult to set up a static 1 to 1 map from logical to physical memory, with some pages protected. There is no need for an operating system (Just implement the minimal set of features that you need).

If you CPU has segments then it is easier (not so common theses days, as there are usually only around 4 segments, so not very flexible).

Answer (score 0):

The `.ro` and `.text` sections are used by the linker to locate constant data and code respectively according to the memory map defined in the linker script.  It does not imply that that memory is read-only protected.

> But then doesn't everything get loaded into RAM anyways?

Not necessarily. Most microcontrollers execute code from, and store constants in ROM (typically on-chip flash). This ROM is typically slower than RAM and faster MCUs have accelerators or caches to compensate.  Also often they employ Harvard architecture   (separate busses for code and data) allowing simultaneous fetch of code and data.

Some MCUs (some ARM Cortex-M devices for example) incorporate an MMU that supports the protection of memory areas. However `.ro` and `.text` do not on its own cause the MMU to be used, that is a matter for the runtime environment initialisation code.

So it depends on the system and architecture, and there are many permutations, but in brief `.ro` and `.text` do not guarantee that the content of those regions is protected at runtime.